# How do I redirect the user from within a getJSON call?

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

im receiving a json file from an external call. If the json comes with a null value (possible if the user session is expired) then the user should be redirected to the logout.php page. In my current call, instead of redirecting, the logout.php data is being received as a json response.

So, how do I redirect the user when the json data is null?

```
$.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
    if(json !== null) {
        fnCallback(json);
    } else {
        window.location.href = "logout.php";
    }
});
```

Thanks to @Ron's observation i noticed that, although sSource was calling the right file (datatables.php), its header isn't detecting the request method, hence returning the wrong data:

```
if(($_SESSION['login_expire'] + $session['expiration_time']) < time()) {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        # forms
    } else {
        if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            # datatable
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(null);
        } else {
            # get
            header('Location: '.URL_CMS.'logout.php?expired=true');
        }
    }
    die();
} else {
    # update expiration time
    $_SESSION['login_expire'] = time();
}
```

That last bit controls idle times. It should also consider ajax calls, in which case it should return a json_encode(null) string instead of redirecting via php:

`if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')`

Comment: I dont get this sentence: " However, all the logout.php data is being received as the json response."

Comment: @Ron the logout.php data is being received as a json response in the Developers Tools > Network tab

Comment: are you sure your sSource is not 'logout.php' ? you can console.log it

Comment: This might be a stupid question but would it not be better to use .ajax ? That way you can get a proper error returned ...

Comment: @Ron nope, my sSource is datatables.php. But thanks to your observation i noticed that the datatables.php session handler wasn't quite detecting the request method. I'm updating my question with the detailed info right now.

Comment: @Pogrindis it turned out to be the sSource header, it is not recognizing the $.getJSON call as a $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=xmlhttprequest

Comment: @andufo thats interesting actually.. Must try reproduce this.

Comment: @Pogrindis thanks, i just fixed the code in case you want to use it. You can place that bit as header for all your session secured pages. It covers normal GET requests, the ones through getJSON (also GET calls) and still haven't figured out the resolution for POST calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is for your PHP to return some JSON that includes a response status and then use that response to send them to the error page if it's a bad status.  For example, have your PHP return `{"status":"failed", "message":"Expired"}` instead of setting the Location header like it is currently.

Then in your Javascript:

```
if(json.status != "failed") {
    fnCallback(json);
} else {
    window.location.href = "logout.php";
}
```